# Extract file with a name filter with VBA

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I need to extract one file, out of two autogenerated files, from a folder.

At the end of each file name there is the date and time.

The date is easy to get, but I'm getting stuck with the time because this is in "01h01m01s" format.

Is there a way to solve this using RegEx?

Here are the file names as they appear in Explorer:

[image: IMG1]

Here's a sample of my code:

```
arquivo = "C:\pathname\file_2018_12_27-01h15m22s.zip"
Caminho = "C:pathname\"

strDate = Format(Now, " dd-mm-yy")
NewFolder = Path & "Extracted" & strDate & "\"

MkDir NewFolder
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
'Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oApp.Namespace(NewFolder).copyhere oApp.Namespace(file).items
```

Comment: Please don't link to images that contain text which could easily be formatted and included in your question.

Comment: It isn't regex, but left(right(filename,13),2) = hour, left(right(filename,10),2) = min, left(right(filename,7),2) = sec.

Comment: @chb, Sorry. I've realized that as soon as I submitted my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function GetTime(s$)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "\d{2}h\d{2}m\d{2}s"
        GetTime = .Execute(s)(0)
    End With
End Function

Sub test()
    MsgBox GetTime("Farol de RC_Celulas de Cto_2018.12.26_07h47m50s.zip")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It fits perfectly on my needs